# Kubernetes - does not start the role of master

Tags: kubernetes

I'm starting a Kubernetes cluster of 3 nodes (1 master, 2 worker)

Trying to go by steps described in Ansible playbook - https://gitlab.com/LinarNadyrov/gcp/tree/master

Applying playbook steps 1,2,3 consequentially

After than, I connect to master to check status:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION

master NotReady master 17m v1.13.0

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Status is NotReady

Could anyone help me with it? What's the problem? What should be done to fix it? Maybe I missed something?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Hello Линар Надыров! It would help if you could post the command you ran to check the cluster status and possibly your .kube config file.  Be sure to remove any secrets.

Comment: Executed command - kubectl get pods -n kube-system / Result - https://yadi.sk/i/c_KALwkErwkiVQ